# Reading data from body in Nuxt 3 API

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to read the body from the request in a Nuxt 3 API endpoint using `useBody` but the result is an object rather than just the raw value of the body parameter. Am I suppose to read the value from `body.username._value` or am I parsing it wrong?

**Example of parsed body**

```js
username: {
    __v_isShallow: false,
    dep: { w: 0, n: 0 },
    __v_isRef: true,
    _rawValue: 'john',
    _value: 'john'
  },
  password: {
    __v_isShallow: false,
    dep: { w: 0, n: 0 },
    __v_isRef: true,
    _rawValue: '123',
    _value: '123'
  }
}
```

**Example of request**

```js
useFetch('/api/login', { method: 'post', body: { username: 'john', password: '123' }, initialCache: false })
```

Comment: This is a ref, so you access it with `variable.value` like `username.value`.

Comment: More details are available here: https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref

Comment: I can only read it through `._value`, and not `.value`. Am I missing something?

Comment: How do you read it? Gave a try to that one: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/data-fetching#usefetch

Comment: `username.value === '123'` -> false
`username._value === '123'` -> true

Comment: Please give a read to that page: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html and update your question with more of what you're doing so that we could see what is wrong. Keep in mind that `console.log` is not the most effective way to debug usually.

Comment: You may also look into this one: https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-utilities.html#unref But it's probably not even needed overall.